# How to initialize Identity only upon database creation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

New to MVC.

I seem to be stuck in a  bit of a Catch-21 (not quite as severe as a Catch-22).

To keep unnecessary database traffic down, I'd like to call my method to populate the initial Identity data (create admin user, admin role, etc.) only when the database is first created (e.g. during `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists(Of ApplicationDbContext)`).

The trouble stems from the fact that my Startup config must set the `DbContext` first, before `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationSignInManager` are set:

```
Builder.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
Builder.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
Builder.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)
```

The `ApplicationUserManager.Create()` method calls `ApplicationDbContext`, so the calls have to be in that order.

Here's the relevant bit of my Identity initialization code:

```
Public Shared Sub InitializeIdentity()
  Dim oUserManager As ApplicationUserManager
  Dim oRoleManager As ApplicationRoleManager

  oUserManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext.GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)
  oRoleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext.Get(Of ApplicationRoleManager)

  ...

End Sub
```

See the problem? `ApplicationUserManager` relies on `ApplicationDbContext` and `ApplicationDbContext` relies on `ApplicationUserManager` (the latter only when I try to run `InitializeIdentity()` from the overridden `Migrations.Configuration.Seed()` method).

Sure, I could put the `InitializeIdentity()` call elsewhere in my startup, but then it'd run on every single page load when it only needs to run once when the database is first created. That's a huge amount of completely unnecessary hits to the database.

Is there a way to escape this logic loop? How can I tell the framework to run the Identity initialization *after* `ApplicationUserManager` is set—only once, upon database creation—when the context has to be set first?

Comment: Initializers also have a seed that is only called on database creation. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526215/seed-entities-and-users-roles/29547994#29547994

Comment: For some odd reason, the `Seed()` method is never called when using that construct, at least not in my code. In fact I'd tried that approach earlier and abandoned it for this very reason. Do have any guess as to why `Seed()` isn't running?

Comment: It won't run if the database exists. Delete the database or use a different initializer like [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Pardon me, I failed to mention that. I'm manually deleting the database on each test run. The seed method is never called. I'm finding other discussions that seem to indicate this as a bug in EF. So if your version is working I'm surprised.

Comment: Your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547994) turned out to provide the solution for me. Until I saw that, I wasn't aware of how to instantiate `UserManager` and `RoleManager` as completely new objects, instead of attempting to get them from the OWIN context (where they didn't exist yet). If you'd like to make this into an answer here, I'd be pleased to accept it.